# AngularJS Shows its own tags while page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am making an application with **angular js**. I am binding content in the page using **{{ data.content }}** method, this works fine, but while loading the web page browser shows the same code in the page.

see the screenshot I've taken while page loading

[click here](http://s18.postimg.org/9l0f4522h/asd.png)

is there any way to clear this without using **ng-bind** method ?

**EDIT**

I have tried this method

1 -added ng-clock for body

```
<body ng-app="MyApp"   ng-cloack ng-controller="MyController" >
```

2 -added css style for ng-clock

```
  [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

but still the same problem persists.

and I'm using latest version of both *chorme* and *mozilla firefox*

Comment: So it's not that it is flashing the uncompiled page then ... It's more the page doesn't work? Any errors in the console?

Comment: ng-cloack ? ng-cloak

Comment: @PSL oohhh... I'll edit and check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the issue is the delay in angular compiling the page when it first downloads. Take a look at `ngCloak` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak.

> The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

So, add this to your CSS file:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

And in your html:

```
<body ng-cloak>
```

Note, for legacy browser 'support' (e.g. IE7), it would need to be:

```
<body ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
```

Comment: Great! It pays off!

Answer (score 1):

Add below code, ngCloak prevent template being displayed while loading.

```
<style>
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

and then call this class in body tag:

```
<body ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak